# Need some help on how to replay the last game of a java maze game

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on creating a Java maze game for a project. The maze is displayed on the console as standard output not in an applet. I have created most of hte code I need, however I am stuck at one problem and that is I need a user to be able to replay the last game i.e redraw the maze with the users moves but without any input from the user.

I am not sure on what course of action to take, i was thinking about copying each users move or the position of each move into another array, as you can see i have 2 variables which hold the position of the player, plyrX and plyrY do you think copying these values into a new array after each move would solve my problem and how would i go about this?

I have updated my code, apologies about the textIO.java class not being present, not sure how to resolve that exept post a link to TextIO.java [TextIO.java][1]

My code below is updated with a new array of type char to hold values from the original maze (read in from text file and displayed using unicode characters) and also to new variables c_plyrX and c_plyrY which I am thinking should hold the values of plyrX and plyrY and copy them into the new array.

When I try to call the replayGame(); method from the menu the maze loads for a second then the console exits so im not sure what I am doing wrong

Thanks

```
public class MazeGame {

//unicode characters that will define the maze walls,
//pathways, and in game characters.
final static char WALL = '\u2588';  //wall
final static char PATH = '\u2591';  //pathway
final static char PLAYER = '\u25EF';    //player
final static char ENTRANCE = 'E';   //entrance
final static char EXIT = '\u2716';  //exit

//declaring member variables which will hold the maze co-ordinates
//X = rows, Y = columns
static int entX = 0;    //entrance X co-ordinate
static int entY = 1;    //entrance y co-ordinate
static int plyrX = 0;
static int plyrY = 1;
static int exitX = 24;  //exit X co-ordinate
static int exitY = 37;  //exit Y co-ordinate

//static member variables which hold maze values    
//used so values can be accessed from different methods
static int rows;    //rows variable
static int cols;    //columns variable
static char[][] maze;   //defines 2 dimensional array to hold the maze

//variables that hold player movement values
static char dir;    //direction
static int spaces;  //amount of spaces user can travel

//variable to hold amount of moves the user has taken;
static int movesTaken = 0;

//new array to hold player moves for replaying game
static char[][] mazeCopy;
static int c_plyrX;
static int c_plyrY;

/** userMenu method for displaying the user menu which will provide various options for
 * the user to choose such as play a maze game, get instructions, etc.
 */
public static void userMenu(){

    TextIO.putln("Maze Game");
    TextIO.putln("*********");
    TextIO.putln("Choose an option.");
    TextIO.putln("");
    TextIO.putln("1. Play the Maze Game.");
    TextIO.putln("2. View Instructions.");
    TextIO.putln("3. Replay the last game.");
    TextIO.putln("4. Exit the Maze Game.");
    TextIO.putln("");

    int option; //variable for holding users option

    TextIO.put("Type your choice: ");
    option = TextIO.getlnInt(); //gets users option

    //switch statement for processing menu options
    switch(option){
    case 1: playMazeGame(); break;
    case 2: instructions(); break;
    case 3: if (c_plyrX == plyrX && c_plyrY == plyrY)replayGame();
    else {
        TextIO.putln("Option not available yet, you need to play a game first.");
        TextIO.putln();
        userMenu();
    }
    break;
    case 4: System.exit(0); break;//exits the user out of the console
    default: TextIO.put("Option must be 1, 2, 3 or 4");break;
    }
}   //end of userMenu

/**main method, will call the userMenu and get the users choice and call
 * the relevant method to execute the users choice.
 */

public static void main(String[]args){

    userMenu(); //calls the userMenu method

    }   //end of main method

/**instructions method, displays instructions on how to play
 * the game to the user/
 */
public static void instructions(){

    TextIO.putln("To beat the Maze Game you have to move your character");
    TextIO.putln("through the maze and reach the exit in as few moves as possible.");
    TextIO.putln("");
    TextIO.putln("Your characer is displayed as a " + PLAYER);
    TextIO.putln("The maze exit is displayed as a " + EXIT);
    TextIO.putln("Reach the exit and you have won escaped the maze.");
    TextIO.putln("To control your character type the direction you want to go");
    TextIO.putln("and how many spaces you want to move");
    TextIO.putln("for example 'D3' will move your character");
    TextIO.putln("down 3 spaces.");
    TextIO.putln("Remember you can't walk through walls!");

    boolean insOption;  //boolean variable

    TextIO.putln("");
    TextIO.put("Do you want to play the Maze Game now? (Y or N) ");
    insOption = TextIO.getlnBoolean();

    if (insOption == true)playMazeGame();
    else userMenu();
}   //end of instructions method

/**playMazeGame method, calls the loadMaze method and the charMove method
 * to start playing the Maze Game.
 */

public static void playMazeGame(){

    loadMaze();
    plyrMoves();

}   //end of playMazeGame method

/**loadMaze method, loads the 39x25 maze from the MazeGame.txt text file 
 * and inserts values from the text file into the maze array and 
 * displays the maze on screen using the unicode block characters.
 * plyrX and plyrY variables are set at their staring co ordinates so that when
 * a game is completed and the user selects to play a new game
 * the player character will always be at position 01.
 */

public static void loadMaze(){

    plyrX = 0;
    plyrY = 1;

    TextIO.readFile("MazeGame.txt");    //now reads from the external MazeGame.txt file

    rows = TextIO.getInt(); //gets the number of rows from text file to create X dimensions
    cols = TextIO.getlnInt();   //gets number of columns from text file to create Y dimensions

    maze = new char[rows][cols];    //creates maze array of base type char with specified dimnensions

    //loop to process the array and read in values from the text file.
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            maze[i][j] = TextIO.getChar();
        }
        TextIO.getln();
    }   //end for loop

    TextIO.readStandardInput(); //closes MazeGame.txt file and reads from
                                //standard input.

    //loop to process the array values and display as unicode characters
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            if (i == plyrX && j == plyrY){
                plyrX = i;
                plyrY = j;
                TextIO.put(PLAYER); //puts the player character at  player co-ords
            }
            else{
            if (maze[i][j] == '0') TextIO.putf("%c",WALL);  //puts wall block
            if (maze[i][j] == '1') TextIO.putf("%c",PATH);  //puts path block
            if (maze[i][j] == '2') {
                entX = i;
                entY = j;
                TextIO.putf("%c",ENTRANCE); //puts entrance character
            }
            if (maze[i][j] == '3') {
                exitX = i;  //holds value of exit
                exitY = j;  //co-ordinates
                TextIO.putf("%c",EXIT); //puts exit character           
            }
            }

        }
        TextIO.putln();
    }   //end for loop

}   //end of loadMaze method

/**redrawMaze method, method for redrawing the maze after each move.
 * 
 */

public static void redrawMaze(){

TextIO.readFile("MazeGame.txt");    //now reads from the external MazeGame.txt file

    rows = TextIO.getInt(); //gets the number of rows from text file to create X dimensions
    cols = TextIO.getlnInt();   //gets number of columns from text file to create Y dimensions

    maze = new char[rows][cols];    //creates maze array of base type char with specified dimnensions

    //loop to process the array and read in values from the text file.
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            maze[i][j] = TextIO.getChar();
        }
        TextIO.getln();
    }   //end for loop

    TextIO.readStandardInput(); //closes MazeGame.txt file and reads from
                                //standard input.

    //loop to process the array values and display as unicode characters
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            if (i == plyrX && j == plyrY){
                plyrX = i;
                plyrY = j;
                TextIO.put(PLAYER); //puts the player character at  player co-ords
            }
            else{
            if (maze[i][j] == '0') TextIO.putf("%c",WALL);  //puts wall block
            if (maze[i][j] == '1') TextIO.putf("%c",PATH);  //puts path block
            if (maze[i][j] == '2') {
                entX = i;
                entY = j;
                TextIO.putf("%c",ENTRANCE); //puts entrance character
            }
            if (maze[i][j] == '3') {
                exitX = i;  //holds value of exit
                exitY = j;  //co-ordinates
                TextIO.putf("%c",EXIT); //puts exit character           
            }
            }

        }
        TextIO.putln();
    }   //end for loop

}   //end redrawMaze method

/**replay game method
 * 
 */

public static void replayGame(){

TextIO.readFile("MazeGame.txt");    //now reads from the external MazeGame.txt file

    rows = TextIO.getInt(); //gets the number of rows from text file to create X dimensions
    cols = TextIO.getlnInt();   //gets number of columns from text file to create Y dimensions

    mazeCopy = new char[rows][cols];    //creates maze array of base type char with specified dimnensions

    //loop to process the array and read in values from the text file.
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            mazeCopy[i][j] = TextIO.getChar();
        }
        TextIO.getln();
    }   //end for loop

    TextIO.readStandardInput(); //closes MazeGame.txt file and reads from
                                //standard input.

    //loop to process the array values and display as unicode characters
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            if (i == c_plyrX && j == c_plyrY){
                c_plyrX = i;
                c_plyrY = j;
                TextIO.put(PLAYER); //puts the player character at  player co-ords
            }
            else{
            if (mazeCopy[i][j] == '0') TextIO.putf("%c",WALL);  //puts wall block
            if (mazeCopy[i][j] == '1') TextIO.putf("%c",PATH);  //puts path block
            if (mazeCopy[i][j] == '2') {
                entX = i;
                entY = j;
                TextIO.putf("%c",ENTRANCE); //puts entrance character
            }
            if (mazeCopy[i][j] == '3') {
                exitX = i;  //holds value of exit
                exitY = j;  //co-ordinates
                TextIO.putf("%c",EXIT); //puts exit character           
            }
            }

        }
        TextIO.putln();
    }   //end for loop

    TextIO.putln("postion at " + mazeCopy[c_plyrX][c_plyrY]);

}   //end replayGame method

/**plyrMoves method, method for moving the players character
 * around the maze.
 */

public static void plyrMoves(){

    int nplyrX = plyrX;
    int nplyrY = plyrY;
    int pMoves;

    direction();

    //UP
    if (dir == 'U' || dir == 'u'){

        nplyrX = plyrX;
        nplyrY = plyrY;
        c_plyrX = plyrX;
        c_plyrY = plyrY;

        for(pMoves = 0; pMoves <= spaces; pMoves++){
            if (maze[nplyrX][nplyrY] == '0'){
                TextIO.putln("Invalid move, try again.");
            }
            else if (pMoves != spaces){
                nplyrX =plyrX + 1;
                c_plyrX = nplyrX;
            }
            else {
                plyrX = plyrX-spaces;
                c_plyrX = plyrX;
                movesTaken++;
            }
        }

    }//end UP if

    //DOWN
    if (dir == 'D' || dir == 'd'){

        nplyrX = plyrX;
        nplyrY = plyrY;
        c_plyrX = plyrX;
        c_plyrY = plyrY;


        for (pMoves = 0; pMoves <= spaces; pMoves ++){
            if (maze[nplyrX][nplyrY] == '0'){
                TextIO.putln("Invalid move, try again");
            }
            else if (pMoves != spaces){
                nplyrX = plyrX+1;
                c_plyrX = nplyrX;
            }
            else{
                plyrX = plyrX+spaces;
                c_plyrX = plyrX;
                movesTaken++;
            }
        }

    }   //end DOWN if

    //LEFT
    if (dir == 'L' || dir =='l'){

        nplyrX = plyrX;
        nplyrY = plyrY;
        c_plyrX = plyrX;
        c_plyrY = plyrY;

        for (pMoves = 0; pMoves <= spaces; pMoves++){
            if (maze[nplyrX][nplyrY] == '0'){
                TextIO.putln("Invalid move, try again");
            }
            else if (pMoves != spaces){
                nplyrY = plyrY + 1;
                c_plyrY = nplyrY;
            }
            else{
                plyrY = plyrY-spaces;
                c_plyrY = plyrY;
                movesTaken++;
            }
        }
    }   //end LEFT if

    //RIGHT
    if (dir == 'R' || dir == 'r'){

        nplyrX = plyrX;
        nplyrY = plyrY;
        c_plyrX = plyrX;
        c_plyrY = plyrY;

        for (pMoves = 0; pMoves <= spaces; pMoves++){
            if (maze[nplyrX][nplyrY] == '0'){
                TextIO.putln("Invalid move, try again.");
            }
            else if (pMoves != spaces){
                nplyrY = plyrY + 1;
                c_plyrY = nplyrY;
            }
            else{
                plyrY = plyrY+spaces;
                c_plyrY = plyrY;
                movesTaken++;
            }
        }

    }   //end RIGHT if

    //prints message if player escapes from the maze.
    if (maze[plyrX][plyrY] == '3'){
        TextIO.putln("****Congratulations****");
        TextIO.putln();
        TextIO.putln("You have escaped from the maze.");
        TextIO.putln();

        userMenu();

    }
    else{
        movesTaken++;
        redrawMaze();
        plyrMoves();
    }



}   //end of plyrMoves method

/**direction, method
 * 
 */
public static char direction(){
    TextIO.putln("Enter the direction you wish to move in and the distance");
    TextIO.putln("i.e D3 = move down 3 spaces");
    TextIO.putln("U - Up, D - Down, L - Left, R - Right: ");
    dir = TextIO.getChar();

    if (dir =='U' || dir == 'D' || dir == 'L' || dir == 'R'
        || dir == 'u' || dir == 'd' || dir == 'l' || dir == 'r'){
        spacesMoved();
    }
    else{
        loadMaze();
        TextIO.putln("Invalid direction!");
        TextIO.put("Direction must be one of U, D, L or R");
        direction();
    }

    return dir; //returns the value of dir (direction)

}   //end direction method

/**spaces method, gets the amount of spaces the user wants to move
 * 
 */

public static int spacesMoved(){
    TextIO.putln(" ");
    spaces = TextIO.getlnInt();

    if (spaces  <= 0){

    redrawMaze();
    TextIO.put("Invalid amount of spaces, type spaces again");
    spacesMoved();
    }

    return spaces;
}   //end spacesMoved method 


}   //end of MazeGame class
```

Comment: You should reformat your question so that the code is readable, see the stackoverflow [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: The 384 lines of code posted does not compile because the TextIO class is missing.  For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply record the player moves to an array and play them back from there.

Comment: can you give me a hint on what the code might be? would the new array be the same size as the orginal maze array? Thanks

Comment: He doesn't need to set up an observer pattern. Unless that's silly jargon for 'put the update code by the move code'. What he needs is an appendable list.

Comment: What about if I record the position in the array after each move and copy that? i.e at the start of the game player is at element 01 after the first move player is at element 07, can i record the postion after each move and use that to replay the game? thanks

Comment: The array will be variable, since it's the number of moves the player makes, but ultimately it can be larger than the original maze array because the player can make moves that double back, etc. You could setup an observer pattern to watch the Player make moves, and record those moves to the array.

Comment: @Marty, yep that'll do it, ArrayList is probably the best container for this list.

Comment: Hi sorry still struggling to understand how to do this, when I call the replayGame() method the maze displays but the character is in the last position that plyrX & plyrY was in, im not sure how to re display the maze from replayGame() showing the positions afetr each move. Thanks